# How many video cameras are used for cricket broadcasting?

Tags: cricket, media, indian-premier-league, cricket-world-cup

How many video cameras are used for broadcasting an international cricket match?

Especially for the current world T20i, they are covering the each and every corner of the stadium. I would like to know the number of cameras used for that including stump cameras and spider cams.

I think these numbers will also be equal to IPL. Is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Source](http://www.icc-cricket.com/news/2014/media-releases/78883/icc-world-twenty20-bangladesh-2014-set-to-break-broadcast-records), it will be around **28** Cameras.

> The production will be among the most sophisticated ever too, with 28
>   cameras,  including seven ultra-motion cameras, Spidercam as well as
>   graphics with key   analytics, all of which will take the viewer right
>   to the heart of the action.